# OpenOCD GDB executable "arm-none-eabi-gdb" was not found. Please configure "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath" correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

I am using the Raspberry Pico and attempting to use the debugging tool in VS Code from VSCode on a Raspberry Pi 4, but I am getting the following error:

`OpenOCD GDB executable "arm-none-eabi-gdb" was not found. Please configure "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath" correctly.`

I have the following config for launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "TempSensor",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "executable": "/home/pi/pico/devices/build/tempSensor/tempSensor.elf",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "servertype": "openocd",
            // This may need to be arm-none-eabi-gdb depending on your system
            "gdbpath": "gdb-multiarch",
            "device": "RP2040",
            "configFiles": [
                "interface/raspberrypi-swd.cfg",
                "target/rp2040.cfg"
            ],
            "svdFile": "/home/pi/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/hardware_regs/rp2040.svd",
            "runToMain": true,
            // Work around for stopping at main on restart
            "postRestartCommands": [
                "break main",
                "continue"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following code for settings.json

```
{
    // These settings tweaks to the cmake plugin will ensure
    // that you debug using cortex-debug instead of trying to launch
    // a Pico binary on the host
    "cmake.statusbar.advanced": {
        "debug": {
            "visibility": "hidden"
        },
        "launch": {
            "visibility": "hidden"
        }
    },
    "cmake.buildBeforeRun": true,
    "C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": false
}
```

Comment: Also having this issue. Did you manage to fix this? I was following the C++ SDK guide. (https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf) And followed the Chapter 2 instructions and then went to Chapter 6. I believe I've done everything that it has asked there. I even have `gdb-multiarch` installed correctly and as you've shown above, that's what's in the `.vscode/launch.json` file but somewhere else it's asking for the `arm-non-eabi-gdb` executable even tho the configuration file says something different. Perhaps because of `cortex-debug` type? What should that be then!?

Comment: (I should probably mention that I'm using Pop_OS 20.10 on an Intel x86_64 chip -- I had to do some minor editing like installing VSCode from my package manager and setting `SKIP_VSCODE=1` in the `pico_setup.sh` installer because I wasn't on a Pi.)

Comment: Yep. See below!

Comment: Did I miss something? There is nothing below.

Comment: Try again, my original answer was removed by a moderator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been a fix recently in the documentation.

As explained in this link: https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/issues/8

When setting a Raspberry Pi up as described in the Getting Started guide, two problems arise when launching the debugger:

Setting "gdbpath" in launch.json is marked as not allowed
When launching the setting is ignored, and arm-none-eabi-gdb is used, which is unavailable
It seems that setting "cortex-debug.gdbpath" can only be set in settings.json

So remove.

"gdbpath" : "gdb-multiarch" from launch.json and add "cortex-debug.gdbPath": "gdb-multiarch" to settings.json.